# How to attach "Stream Attachments" to Facebook's "Stream Stories"?

Tags: facebook

Facebook seems to have a concept called "Stream Attachments". See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/

This document says: "You can add a lot of rich information to a **stream story** by including an **attachment**"
Reading this document, it seems a "Stream Attachment" can contain media such as "images", "flash" and "music" (MP3s).

Here are my questions:

1. Is "Stream Story" synonymous to "[Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)"?
2. What is the URL to attach a Stream Attachment to a specific stream story?
3. In case you use the "media" field, you must provide a JSON structure with all required data. How do you format this JSON structure to http-post it to some receiving URL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes stream story is what you would call a post.

You can make a post three ways:

1 Make an graph api call from your server to fb

It's basically a post to graph.facebook.com/me/feed with a bunch of arguments for the various elements of the post.

If you want flash then add source=www.mysite.com/movei.swf

developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

2 Use fbjs to pop a ui dialog

developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

This has the advantage that the user can preview the post and add a message. You used to be able to populate the message using the graph api, but people spammed it so fb is remvoing that.

3 Direct the user to a url on fb that displays a feed dialog.

This is probably the easiest way.

developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Note, it won't let me put links so I removed all the http:// above

Comment: The [Stream Attachments page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments/) names fields which are not listed on the [Post page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/). For instance **href** and **media**. I'm interested in the media field, because it suggests it's possible to embed an MP3 player in posts. How'd I do this using an HTTP request?